How know the source of a snap packpage?
I know how to open a manifest.yaml and snapcraftf.yaml but I do not know where the source code of the snap is supposed to be. This is because there are a lot of archives in that list and it also makes reference to other snaps that are not the one I am searching for. Where exactly is written the package version where the snap comes from?
Edit: i want to know the snap sources of ubuntu jammy original( not a number added). I read they are not included in the iso source images.

Needs details. What version of Ubuntu are you using? List all the snaps you are asking about. Please do this as an edit to the question, not in the comments.
